# Can anyone tell me what is the easiest way to install Boost.iostreams on Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c++, boost

As in the question, I'm sure it's very simple but I want to make everything as well as I can, so I won't have any problems with Boost in the future. Thanks from advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned on the [Boost.Iostreams install page](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/iostreams/doc/index.html), you will be able to use most features of the library by simply adding the include directory to your project's "Additional Include Directories" field.

[image]

If you require one of the other features provided by Boost.Iostreams, you can either add the cpp files to your project, build it with a makefile, or build it with Boost.Build.

Comment: Okay, I added directory to Boost libs. I can't choose `#include <Boost>` things. What else should I do?

Comment: You need to point to the include directory, not the boost libs.

Comment: Yes, I meant include when I wrote libs. I added include directory and it's still not working.

Comment: What error are you getting? And what're you including specifically?

Comment: I'm not getting any errors, I think I'm including wrong directory. `C:\boost_1_55_0\tools\quickbook\test\include`. I thought I will find `include` folder directly in `boost_1_55_0`, but I didn't. Should I have `include` folder in the main boost folder? I already included another library to Visual Studio and I had this `include` folder.

Comment: Okay, I cannot believe how silly I was. I just included the `C:\boost_1_55_0` and it's working like charm. Sorry for wasting your time and thanks for advice!